# How to prevent last element from moving?

Tags: html, css

Probably a stupid question, but because css is not my best side, I can't figure this out.
I got a second construction:

```
<div>
  <span class="span-chb">
    <input type="checkbox" id="special-chb" name="special-exist">
    <label for="special-chb">Special exist, bla bla bla...</label>
    <span class="tooltip">
      <span>tooltip-text</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

They are placed in line:

```
.span-chb {
  height: 22px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

My issue is when div is resized (its ok, it must change sizes in case of page size changes) tooltip span are jumping to new line. If I make div even smaller, label text are moving, but element itself stays on place.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to not move tooltip or input anywhere, but still allow for label text to move to new line. The closest I got to wanted result is adding `white-space: nowrap;` to `span-chb` but this prevent label text from jumping (basicaly its width stops to change size). Adding `white-space: normal;` to label adds issue when tooltip span placement ends up on the last label line.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `display:table` may help fix this.

Try using the following CSS:

```
.span-chb {
  height: 22px;
  display: table;
}
.span-chb * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.tooltip {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Tried this one, and now I feel myself like an idiot. Seems legit. Except I only needed display:table and table-cell for label, anything else looks unnecessary. Will try to use it to all similar situations (got couples) and if nothing will break into pieces, will mark this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Table may help.

```css
.span-chb {
  height: 22px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="span-chb">
    
    
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" id="special-chb" name="special-exist">
          <label for="special-chb">Special exist, bla bla bla...</label>
          </th>
        <td>
          <span class="tooltip">
            <span>tooltip-text</span>
          </span></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
  </span>
</div>
```